# How to get newly inserted records based on date from AWS ElasticSearch index using query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I'm totally new to AWS ElasticSearch Service.

First I tried to establish connection using python, It was successful.

Then I tried to get a single record from a specific index and bulk records from an index using query.
Like:

`df = es.get(index="demo_data", doc_type="_doc", id="2") -- For getting single record`

`result_dict = es.search(index="demo_data", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}) -- For getting Bulk Records`

Now, I've been trying to fetch only newly inserted records i.e.(It can be a single record or a bulk of records)from that same index based on date using query, but I couldn't get an exact reference, I tried several ways like **filter query with sort** etc... Which either gets me the last record of the index or all the records in descending order.

I couldn't able to get the exact new records based on the date from my previous load.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from pandasticsearch import Select
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()


host = 'ENDPOINT' # ES hostname 
region = 'REGION' # our region ID

service = 'es'

awsauth = AWS4Auth('Secret_Key', 'Secret_ID', region, service)

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

s = Search(index='demo_data').using(es).query("match", date= max(pandas_df.date))
                        
pandas_df = Select.from_dict(s).to_pandas()

display(pandas_df)
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Could you please share your failed queries.

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili I've added my failed script